# Dot product in neural network forward propagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

In neural network forward propagation, when computing the dot product between weight and input, which one come first? Approach 1) or Approach 2)?

1) Weight.dot(Input) + Bias

2) Input.dot(Weight) + Bias

I have seen both approaches. I'm confused.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & linear algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two is the order between the weight and input in a dot product. The [commutative](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m445w04/notes/vector/dotproduct.html) nature of the dot product operation, however, states that the order does not matter; the result will be the same regardless.

That being said, `Weight.dot(Input) + Bias` is what I am most familiar with.

From a math point of view, you would probably consider `Weight.dot(Input)` the method to use as the Weights are considered the coefficients, hence appearing first makes the most logical sense.

From a programmatic point of view it will depend heavily on implementation; it may be preferred to invoke the `dot()` method on the Input Object as opposed to Weight.

Do note that the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is not the same as [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). As you noted, matrix multiplication is not necessarily commutative. The library I primarily use, Tensorflow, implements matrix multiplication using [`tf.matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul). In implementations of neural networks provided the Weights is always used as the second argument, suggesting the second approach would be preferred in this context.

Comment: Thanks. I agree when weight and input are vectors, the sequence doesn't matter. But when they are matrices, the sequence would matter then. I think would also affect how the gradient descent is derived.

Comment: @Bon There's a difference between matrix multiplication and the dot product which I think has caused a bit of confusion. To be adequately sure, I've taken a look at examples from Tensorflow and the weights are always used second. I'll make note of that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The dot product of two vector is commutative. It does not matter if it is input.dot(weight) or weight.dot(input).

Source: http://www.citycollegiate.com/vectorXIh.htm